# How to get VIM to enter normal mode after Command + V paste in insert mode?

Tags: vim, editor, copy-paste, paste

The workflow Id like is as follows

- Im in insert mode
- I paste using `Command + V`
- The text is pasted
- Normal mode is initiated

Currently I remain in insert mode afterwards

Comment: The problem here is getting the system clipboard to play nicely with vimscript. Maybe [this post](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/84/how-can-i-copy-text-to-the-system-clipboard-from-vim) can help you get closer to that?

Comment: Here is a better workflow: stay in normal mode and use Vim's built-in clipboard support: `"+p`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended that you use cmd+v for pasting but here is the solution. Remap your key like this and your register to whatever you use. Position your cursor however you want in the function.

```
function! LeaveInsert() abort
exe "normal! ".'"'."+p "
call feedkeys("\<Esc>")
endfunction

inoremap <c-v>  <Cmd> :call LeaveInsert()<cr>
```